# How do you make a C# server that can store its connection to clients AND update them when needed

Tags: c#, sockets, server, game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer turn based game. I have little experience with c# servers so I am trying to learn. It would need to be able to play something like chess over the internet.

**My Goal**: to have a server that can accept messages from clients (like join game, do a move, etc) and be able to store the Client's connection when they join and then update them on information in the game at any time, like when a opponent moves or something. (I would want to be able to expand it to more than two players)

**My Problem**: everything I can find about c# servers are sockets. The problem with sockets as far as I can tell is that they are one-way connections, meaning a client can only get data **once** after they send data. I would want to be able to update them multiple times after that, showing in close to realtime what happened in the game world after their turn is over.

How would I achieve this? Would I need clients to have listeners too? How do I store a connection when a new socket is created every time that a new request is made?

Thank you for any help/knowledge you can give!

Comment: Sockets are not one-way connections. You can read from, and write into sockets.
- Your server should store all accepted sockets in a List.
- Each time the game changes, it could write the information into the buffer of the stored socket.
- Your client should regularily read from the socket and handle the things it reads. 

BEHOLD: There are more stable approaches to Client/Server applications than sockets. I recommend you look into a WCF tutorial first. It will save a lot of time when you dont have to care about plumbing source code.

Comment: Ok, so instead of opening a new socket for every message sent like the examples have, I would open a socket once from each client and then call the Send or Receive method whenever I need to?

Comment: Yes, but it is a lot of work to write a stable engine, sockets can loose connections while you hold them, etc..  etc.. . I really wouldnt go down the path of manually using sockets. Dive into Frameworks like remoting, wcf, and pick a good start.

Comment: Im using signalR as the answer suggest, it is much simpler. Thank you anyway!

Comment: thats a good choice too

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what sockets do you mean but [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is a technology which, in a few words, enriches HTTP with full duplex communication between client and server. If we are talking about C# look at [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which can use WebSocket.